# How do I connect Prometheus to Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I've got Prometheus and Grafana both running in Linux Docker containers.

[image]
I'd like to configure Grafana to use Prometheus as a data source.

I can access Grafana from my computer, running Windows 10, at http://localhost:3030.

I can also see Prometheus at http://localhost:9090/graph.

I'm trying to add Prometheus as a datasource, and have tried http://host.docker.internal:9090. Grafana claims to successfully ingest:

[image]

But there is no data in the Prometheus dashboard itself:

[image]

The relevant part of docker-compose.yaml is:

```
  prometheus:
build:
  context: ./prometheus
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-local
network_mode: host
ports:
  - 9090:9090
```

What else should I be trying?

Comment: what are your docker configurations?

Comment: This is the relevant part, I think:

  prometheus:
    build: ./prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090

Comment: http://{service_name}:9090 should work without exposing prometheus port, grafana and prometheus have to be in the same docker network

Comment: {service_name} being "prometheus"?

I've edited the post to show the Docker UI.

Comment: Yes, the service_name for prometheus you've defined in your docker-compose.yml.You can also use the container name